# rails fixed header table with varied width

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, tableheader

I'm trying to create a fixed header table in my index view. After 2 days I'm on it, I finally found the jQuery `fixedheadertable` addon, and I still can't use it. I guess I'm doing something wrong because it's the first time I'm using jQuery. This is what I have done:

Added the file `jquery.fixedheadertable.js` to `\app\assets\javascripts`

In `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.fixedheadertable
..
..
```

In `my_js_coffee_file`:

```
$ -> 
    $("#id_of_my_index_table").fixheadertable({
             caption : 'My header is fixed !',
             height  : 200
    });
```

Also tried:

```
$ ->
  $('#id_of_my_index_table').fixedHeaderTable('show');
```

No change at all...
what's wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?  (I'm assuming you use some kind of inspector panel in whatever browser you use to test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `stickyTableHeaders` JQuery plugin solved my problem.

https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have the details to properly analyse what is wrong. However, try these and see if it helps.

Does your application.js have require_tree in it? Also, try adding your my_js_coffee_file in the end of the application.js

Ex :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.fixedheadertable
//= require my_js_coffee_file
```

Or alternatively, you can also code the same thing inside the application.js file itself. And then try running. Check your console log to see what errors pop up.